# How validate two select list in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle apex, and i have 2 select list components that get the elements from the same table. i want build a currency converter, and the list of currency are "divisas"

My problem is: i want validate that when on one select component, one value is selected, the other component doesn't contain that element from select list 1. And vice verse

Also when on select 1 is null on the select 2 must show all result from the table, and vice verse.

I start with this query, but i can't do it works

```
select *
from divisas
where EN_APP = 'S'
  and (
    case when :P12_DIVISA is not null then (cod_divi <> :P12_DIVISA) else EN_APP = 'S' end
  )
;
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60676786/apex-how-to-implement-circular-cascade-select-lists-many-to-many/60678854

Answer (score 0):

There's the **Cascading List of Values** property for Select List items. However, as you want to handle both items at the same time, you'll enter circular reference & *dead loop* so it won't just work.

Here's an option which does what you wanted; see if it helps:

- create two items, e.g. `P59_CURR_1` and `P59_CURR_2` (for two currencies)
- their type is Select List item
- Page action on selection = "Redirect and set value"
- SQL query looks like this (for `P59_CURR_1`)

  ```
  select cod_divi d, cod_divi r
  from divisas
  where cod_divi <> nvl(:P59_CURR_2, 'X')      -- would be `:P59_CURR_1` for another item
  order by cod_divi
  ```
- don't set cascading list of values parent item!

That's it; run the page and see how it behaves. Looks OK to me on apex.oracle.com's Apex 20.1 version.